# Echo in a form when user did not insert all info needed

Tags: php, forms, echo

This is a part of my registration form. I want to display back the input user inserted if they forgot to enter all the info needed. However, I get this on my textbox in register form where everyone including my user can see it. 

**Notice**:Undefined variable: name in **D:\XAMPP\htdocs\registration.php** on line **113**

I want it to echo back the input that user had inserted and display it again so that user does not have to enter the same input over again. Help ?

```
$myusername=($_POST['username']);
$name=($_POST['name']);

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    echo $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}

<input type="text" name="username" size="60" value="<?php echo $myusername; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="name" size="60" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
```

Comment: You must have an error on or near line 113, what's around there?

Comment: **Where is line 113?** You're using `$myname=($_POST['name']);` without checking that it isset, but that would produce and undefined index error not undefined variable.

Comment: Please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you send the user back to the page they were at previously if the form fails to validate, the POST array is emptied. POST will only carry the information to the page that the form is submitting to.

You can use sessions to save the data in an array, indexed by form field name. Then when the user is sent back to the form, if there are any entries in the array, you can iterate over them through to your form fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can controll the variables with `if` clause; means you can write:

```
if ( isset($_POST['send']) && isset($myusername) ) {
echo $myusername;
}
else {
  echo '<span style="color:red;">Please complete this field</span>';
}
```

and do the same in html `value` for textfiels...

Answer (score 0):

```
$myusername = isset($_POST['username']) ? ($_POST['username']) : '';
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? ($_POST['name']) : '';

<input type="text" name="username" size="60" value="<?php echo $myusername; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="name" size="60" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should remove your error?

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $myusername=($_POST['username']);
    <input type="text" name="username" size="60" value="<?php echo $myusername; ?>"/>
    echo $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name=($_POST['name']);
    <input type="text" name="name" size="60" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

Here we are checking for POST value first then we using it.

Answer (score 0):

Write the isset function inside the value of each of your .

Exemple :

```
<input type="text" name="username" size="60" value="
<?php if( isset( $_POST["myusername"] ) ) 
    echo $_POST["myusername"] ?> "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tutorial for validation of input fields in php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

or you can use this method

```
<?php 
$myusername="";
$name="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="username" size="60" value="<?php echo $myusername; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="name" size="60" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" size="60" value="submit"/>
</form>
```